# String Boot application is not loading when hitting URL with capital letter server.servlet.contextPath value

Tags: java, spring-boot, contextpath

I am working on a Spring Boot Application.

*application.properties*

```
server.servlet.contextPath=myapp
```

When I am hitting a base URL as below:

`http://localhost:8080/myapp`, I can see my application is loading

`http://localhost:8080/MYAPP`, I am getting HTTP Status 404.

Not sure why this is happening, can anyone please explain this to me?

Comment: context path is case sensitive

Comment: is there any way I can make context path case insensitive?

Answer (score 0):

For your question in the comment:
`is there any way I can make context path case insensitive?`

Overriding the `configurePathMatch` would work

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        AntPathMatcher pathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();
        pathMatcher.setCaseSensitive(false);
        configurer.setPathMatcher(pathMatcher);
    }
}
```

Note:

- This will be applicable for all your apis
- As of [current spring version](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html#configurePathMatch-org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.PathMatchConfigurer-), it is `Deprecated`.

Comment: The non-deprecated version is https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html#configurePathMatch-org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.PathMatchConfigurer-